# AngularJS, Using a Service to call into a Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am new to Angular, what I would like to accomplish is: From a Service / Factory to call methods directly into a controller.

In the following code, I would like from the valueUserController I would like to create a method from the service myApi and set the value inside the valueController.

Here is my code:

modules/myApi.js

```
var MyApi = app.factory('MyApi', function() 
    var api = {};

    api.getCurrentValue = function() {
        // needs to access the Value controller and return the current value
    }

    api.setCurrentValue = function(value) {
        // needs to access the Value controller and set current value
    }

    api.getValueChangeHistory = function() {
        // access value controller and return all the values
    }

);
```

controllers/value.js

```
app.controller('valueController', function($scope) {

    var value = 0;

    function getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    function setValue(inValue) {
        value = inValue;
    }

    // ......
});
```

controllers/valueUser.js

```
app.controller('valueUserController', function($scope, myApi) {

    function doStuff() {
        var value = myApi.getValue();
        value++;
        myApi.setValue(value);
    }
});
```

I am finding to do this in AngularJS pretty difficult and I haven't found any similar post on here.

Thanks for any help,

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Trying to communicate with a specific controller from a service is not the correct way of thinking. A service needs to be an isolated entity (which usually holds some state), by which controllers are able to interact with.

With this in mind, you can use something like an event pattern to achieve what you are looking for. For example, when your service completes some particular process, you can fire an event like so:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', { myValue: 'someValue' });
```

Then any controller in your system could watch for that event and perform a specific task when required. For example, inside your controller you could do the following:

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
    // Do something here with your value when your service triggers the event
    console.log(data.myValue);
});
```

Comment: I get how events can be used at "setters". But I don't understand how to use events to be used as a getter.

Setter:
    `$rootScope.$broadcast('setValue', { myValue: 'someValue' });`
    `$scope.$on('setValue', function(event, data){ value = data.myValue});`

But for the getter i'm still puzzled

Comment: Don't think of them as getters or setters. Think of services as entities that hold a state. When something within the state changes, you notify the rest of the application through an event.